# In Argu, getting missing argument error for what appears to be an optional parameter

Tags: f#, f#-argu

Here is my code:

```ml
open Argu

type CliArguments = Count of int option
with
    interface IArgParserTemplate with
        member s.Usage =
            match s with Count _ -> "number of items."


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

    let errorHandler = ProcessExiter(colorizer = function ErrorCode.HelpText -> None | _ -> Some System.ConsoleColor.Red)
    let parser = ArgumentParser.Create<CliArguments>(errorHandler = errorHandler)
    let cliArguments = parser.Parse(argv)
    cliArguments.GetResult(Count) |> printfn "Count = %A"

    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Notice that I have defined the Count DU case as an int option. However, when I run the program without command line parameters, I get the following message:

`ERROR: missing argument '--count'.`

I expected that the `--count` parameter would be optional. I expected that the Count result would be `None` if it were not included on the command line.

How do I make the `--count` optional on the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of making the Count case an `int option`, leave it an `int` and call `GetResult(...)` passing in a default value:

```ml
type CliArguments = Count of int
    :
    :
cliArguments.GetResult(Count, defaultValue = 10)
```

*Notes:*

1. It was the call to `GetResult(...)` that was causing the missing argument exception, not the call to `Parse(...)`.
2. There may still be scenarios in which the type of the DU case is an Option. An optional DU type makes the *argument* of the *parameter* optional. It does not make the *parameter* optional. In other words, if Count were an `int option`, then both `--count 10` and `--count` would be valid command line parameters. The first would result in `Some(10)`. The second would result in `None`.